# AbstractList UnsupportedOperationException when calling .sort on a List

Tags: java, android, exception, kotlin, collections

I'm sorting a List using Collections.sort(), which seems to be working every way I can test it.  Some of my users are crashing though.

```
Caused by java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    java.util.AbstractList.set (AbstractList.java:681)
    java.util.AbstractList$FullListIterator.set (AbstractList.java:143)
    java.util.Collections.sort (Collections.java:1909)
    com.myapp.MyFragment.myMethod (MyFragment.java:225)
```

But, all I'm doing is trying to sort a List

```
private void myMethod(List<MyThing> myThings) {

    Collections.sort(myList, (thing1, thing2) -> Long.compare(thing2.getLongValue(), thing1.getLongValue()));
```

I'm noticing this doesnt happen on Android 8 and above. Its only happening on 5.0 - 7.1

The list is instantiated as an ArrayList, populated, and set as a member of an instance of a class as a generic list.  This object is then posted with EventBus.  The list is then mapped and sorted using Kotlin's `map` and `sortedByDescending` functions.  The mapped and sorted list is then passed to `myMethod()`

This Kotlin extension is generating the list passed to this method:

```
fun List<MyThing>.mapAndSort(context: Context): List<MyThing> {
    return mapNotNull {
        when (it.type) {
            type -> it.getTyped(context) //all of these return polymorphic MyThings
            anotherType -> it.getAnotherTyped(context)
            someOtherType -> it.getSomeOtherTyped(context)
            yetAnotherType -> it.getYetAnotherType(context)
            yetOneMoreType -> it.getYetOneMoreType(context)
            finallyLastTyope -> it.getFinallyLastType(context)
            else -> null
        }
    }.sortedByDescending { it.longValue }
}
```

So far I've seen this list be a `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`, and `kotlin.collections.EmptyList`.

I'm thinking this has something to do with EventBus, but may be Kotlin passing a Kotlin collections list type.  Does anyone know exactly what's going on?

Comment: It's not an ArrayList.

Comment: What kind of List is it? Try `Log.d("choose some tag here", "myThings is a "+myThings.getClass().getName());`

Comment: Some lists don't support all the `List` operations. However this list is being made (not shown in your code), it's making a type of list that doesn't support `set`.

Comment: @khelwood, updated. The list sorts perfectly for me every time I've tested and debugged, but my crash logs are showing that some users on OS 5.0-7.1 are crashing intermittently, and unfortunately I cannot reproduce it myself.

Comment: So your Kotlin code is returning an EmptyList which can't be modified.

Comment: @immibis, actually no.. i just observed on a 7.0 emulator an EmptyList get .sort'ed and not crash

Comment: can you add the StackTrace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of this crash seems to be that, internally, `Iterable<T>.sortedWith` (which is used by `Iterable<T>.sortedByDescending`) creates a new list if the size of the `Iterable` is 0 or 1:

```
public fun <T> Iterable<T>.sortedWith(comparator: Comparator<in T>): List<T> {
    if (this is Collection) {
       if (size <= 1) return this.toList() // <-- HERE
       @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
       return (toTypedArray<Any?>() as Array<T>).apply { sortWith(comparator) }.asList()
    }
    return toMutableList().apply { sortWith(comparator) }
}
```

The function `toList()` in turn will call `listOf`:

```
public fun <T> Iterable<T>.toList(): List<T> {
    if (this is Collection) {
        return when (size) {
            0 -> emptyList()
            1 -> listOf(if (this is List) get(0) else iterator().next())
            else -> this.toMutableList()
        }
    }
    return this.toMutableList().optimizeReadOnlyList()
}
```

Which in turn will resolve into either an `EmptyList` (which is safe to sort since it's empty) or a `SingletonList` which doesn't implement `set` from `AbstractList`

Here is some evidence:

https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/s3j6g8476h8047vvvsjuvletlr/rjlkkn3n6117c1aagja8dr1h67

We could potentially have a bug or, at least, an improvement since `sortedWith` could return `this` if it's of type `List`:

```
public fun <T> Iterable<T>.sortedWith(comparator: Comparator<in T>): List<T> {
    if (this is Collection) {
       if (size <= 1) return if(this is List<T>) this else this.toList()
       @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
       return (toTypedArray<Any?>() as Array<T>).apply { sortWith(comparator) }.asList()
    }
    return toMutableList().apply { sortWith(comparator) }
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer! Thank you!

Comment: `toList` is used to return a copy of list because we couldn't guarantee otherwise that result won't be modified if the original list is modified. So we can't return just `this`.

Comment: The exception is not thrown on OS 8.0 and higher, though.

Comment: Good point, however, it could check whether it's mutable or not too.

Comment: Thanks everyone! This was a fun one

Answer (score 7):

`Collections.sort` is an in-place list mutating operation. If you're going to invoke it in your Java method, do only pass a list there that is statically known to be a `MutableList` in Kotlin.

If you have a `List` of unknown mutability, you can get a `MutableList` from it by calling `.toMutableList()` extension function on it.

And if it's not principal to you to have `myMethod` written in Java, you can replace it with `list.sortedByDescending { it.longValue }` call in Kotlin, then you wouldn't need to turn that list into a mutable list first. In fact that's what `mapAndSort` method does in the end, so it looks like there's no need to sort it again.